# Theme's featured image option is not showing up

Tags: theme-development, actions, add-theme-support

I'm new to WordPress development. I watched a video on how to add featured images. For some reason it's not working, and I can't really figure out why. The option for featured image is not showing at all. So I don't really know how to fix it.

I've tried Googling to see if people have experienced the same thing. From what I've seen, it's usually syntax errors. However, I don't think I have that.

- I've tried deleting and adding it on again, but to no avail.
- I've also tried adding an array as a second argument to `add_theme_support`, but still nothing.
- I've also tried having the `add_actions` function before the custom function. That hasn't worked either.
- In addition to that, I tried just having the `add_theme_support` without the `add_action`, but again nothing.

Here is the code in the `functions.php` file:

```php
`add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'Image_theme_setup' );
function Image_theme_setup() { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I like to know that you are using a custom post type and in that you want to add featured image support, if yes then you need to write extra code in functions.php of theme.

```
$post_type_name  = new Cuztom_Post_Type( 'your-custom-post-type', array(
'supports' => array('thumbnail')
```

));

Answer (score 1):

WordPress editor will add the option to add featured image to your posts, when you add code like the following in the theme's `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_featured_image_setup' );
function theme_featured_image_setup() { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

> **Note:** make sure you didn't include the back-ticks (``) with the code. Sometimes copying code from the web causes small issues like that.

So unless you've made an error somewhere in your code, the editor option should show up. So:

- Make sure you've activated the correct theme.
- Make sure your `functions.php` file has the correct file name.
- Make sure your `functions.php` file has no error in the code. You may provide the full `functions.php` code exactly as it is, for someone to take a look at. But before that, check PHP error log to see if it's generating any error.

Also, after you've done everything correctly, you must add the following function call in a theme template file (for example in `single.php`), for the featured image to show up in the frontend:

```php
the_post_thumbnail();
```

I can't think of any other reason why it shouldn't work.